# VS2008 publish asp.net mvc application on the same pc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

"Publish succeed" appears in the status bar...
I execute IE8 , the home page is ok.
but the links to other views gives "Erreur HTTP 404.0 - Not Found".
The controler redirection do not work.
Under VS2008 IDE the "build and run" works fine.
Some basic things omited?...
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where are you publishing it to? An IIS6 web server?

Comment: I use vs2008 to program an ASP.NET MVC application. Running using "Start debuging" button works fine. For the 1st time, I want to "Publish" in the same PC, only for testing to run directly under IE8 (without VS2008 IDE). the home page is ok. but when i choose to display other views, this message appears "Erreur HTTP 404.0 - Not Found". Are there some and what ASP.NET MVC special things to do on IIS7 manager?  thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of IIS do you have? Try this link: http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx

Root page has Default.aspx but everything else usually needs routing/mapping on IIS to be setup properly.

Comment: Thank you very much queen3 !.. I finaly resolved the problem (bad web site creation under IIS7 manager ) by reading the link you gived :  http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx